# phtml file doesn't appear in server

Tags: magento

I've created a phtml file for custom rss feed in Magento. Then called it on my template using

```
$this->getChildHtml('rssfeed').
```

I've also added it on my page.xml using

```
<block type="core/template".../>.
```

Strangely, it works on one server but when I started adding it on a different server, it won't appear anymore. What are possible causes of this? I've cleared all cache and reindexed but it still won't appear.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Are you sure you moved the template file on your new server? Are you sure you placed it in the right theme? Also be careful at the file naming. On windows the file names are case insensitive, on unix they are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes I have. I didn't change a single line of code, not even a word in any of my templates or phtml files. It won't show. I've triple checked the syntax and everything is correct.

Comment: I am asssuming that u have created the Layout properly. Where have you placed the phtml file ? In a separate theme ?? If yes then please check if you have applied the theme from the Admin. You can use template path hints to see if your block is called or not, that way u wil get a fair Idea

Comment: It's in the same theme. I had to remove it for now on my layout html because all of the html files and blocks I call after it stops working. If it helps, I've added another html file in the same file path and it works.

Answer (score 2):

you can also call any phtml file like below  i think this is easy to use at any .phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm. I've already tried this before and it didn't work. I got error and if I'm not mistaken, this is for static blocks. The phtml file I've added isn't a static block. I call it directly on the site like the sidebar and footer.

Comment: no it's not only for call static block but also call .phtml file as i have used this code in my site and it's working properly.you have to create teplatefolder/templatefile.phtml in your working theme to call this.

Comment: thanks for the help. Anyway, we had to reinstall magento on the server because we were having problems with some settings. After reinstalling  magento, it showed up with no problems so I'd reckon the problem had something to do with the magento installation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically the case sensitiveness, Please check for it.

Comment: The code I've added is same as the other getChildHtml lines I have on the template. The only difference is the name so I'm not so sure it has anything to do with that.